# How to get startsWith function to return values, not Boolean

Tags: r, string, startswith

I am using the `startsWith` function and I want it to return values, not Booleans.

```
string <- ("dem_seat", "factor(state)CT", "factor(state)DE")
```

```
startsWith(string , "factor(state)")
> FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I'd like it to return:

```
> "factor(state)CT" "factor(state)DE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` with `value = TRUE` (by default, it return the numeric index or position index)

```
grep("^factor\\(state\\)", string, value = TRUE)
```

---

If we have a logical vector, we can use that as index to subset

```
string[startsWith(string , "factor(state)")]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_subset` from `stringr` :

```
library(stringr)

string <- c("dem_seat", "factor(state)CT", "factor(state)DE")
str_subset(string, fixed("factor(state)"))
#[1] "factor(state)CT" "factor(state)DE"
```